# Get part of path for the absolute path of a file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm struggling with this problem, i'm new with batch scripting.

I have the absolute path of a file,

```
pathStr = "C:/a_folder/another_folder/com/project/files/my_file.properties"
```

And i need to know how can i extract the following part of that path.

```
subStr = "com/project/files/my_file" (without the extension of the file)
```

If this can help: the `com`folder is always present in the absolute path. The only thing that varies are the names of the folders that are behind and in front of it

i don't know if this is possible, please can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: If I understand correctly, further to removing the file extension, you also want to remove `C:/a_folder/another_folder/`?

Comment: `for %%a in ("%pathStr%") do set "subStr=%%~PNa"` followed by `set "substr=%substr:*com/=com/%"`

Comment: Hi Aacini, i can't be able to execute your code.. those two SET are inside of the loop for? for example... `for %%a in ("%pathStr%") do ( set "subStr=%%~PNa" set "substr=%substr:*com/=com/%" )` excuse my ignorance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Define your starting full path
set "fullPath=C:/a_folder/another_folder/com/project/files/my_file.properties"

:: Remove the extension (also converts / into \)
for %%F in ("%fullPath%") do set "newPath=%%~pnF"

:: Remove the path before com\
set "newPath=%newPath:*\com\=com\%"

:: Display the result
echo newPath="%newPath%"

:: If you want to restore forward slashes for some reason
set "newPath=%newPath:\=/%"

:: Display final result
echo newPath="%newPath%"
```

--OUTPUT--

```
newPath="com\project\files\my_file"
newPath="com/project/files/my_file"
```